# Jackson sorts JSON serialized output keys alphabetically on Android

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am building an android application and I want it to serialize some Java objects to String JSON output. I am using the Jackson library.

I have built a method that takes the object as input and outputs the String JSON.
When this code runs on my computer I get the JSON output correctly, meaning that the output keys maintain the order by which they are declared in my object. When the code runs on an android phone using Android Studio, the keys are sorted alphabetically.
This is unwanted in my case.

Here is the code:

```
public String toJSON(Object obj){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

    try {

        // Convert object to JSON string
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        return jsonInString;

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error";
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly tell Jackson what order you want you properties in using an annotation. See this...

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-property-order-annotation.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This fixes the problem. However, I cannot understand why jackson sorts alphabetically on Android and not on my PC. Calling code is the same!

Comment: Do you use the same version of `Jackson` library on both: `PC` and `Android`?

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes, the jars are loaded in Android Studio and everything runs from there.